# How to checksum and verify all files on a filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, checksum

I would like to run sha1sum or md5sum on all my files recursively, store the results to a file (or a couple of files) and then be able to scan through the files again to verify the integrity of the files.

tools like sha1sum / md5sum does not allow for recursive, and I would also like to spread the load so it uses more than one CPU core.

I do not yet feel safe putting my files on BTRFS and besides BTRFS does not yet work properly on raid5/6 so I am looking for a "quick" way to checksum all my files and verify them whenever I want. That way I would at least know if silent data corruption have hampered any of my files.

Does any tools exist that is designed for this purpose (yes, I am aware of SnapRAID)

Comment: How about ZFS? It is available on Linux, too, from what I've heard. I mean, I would avoid manual periodic scripts. This is not very reliable.

Comment: What about `find -f / - exec md5sum {} \; > logfile.md5sum` ? and use that file after?

Comment: @Hastur : In Debian your command does not work. If anything it have to look like this:    'find -type f /path/ -exec md5sum {} \; >checksums' and to check it you could use    'md5sum -c checksums | grep ":FAILED" >checksumfailures'

Answer (score 2):

These tools are intended for more or less this use case:

http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Hashdeep is especially useful. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

Or you could write something on your own;) 
I wrote this script in Python merging other people snippets from the web.
It can be a starting point.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import hashlib
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import json

BASE_DIR = "/home/p/music"
NUM_PROC = 2
OUT_FILE = "hashes.json"

# list of files to be processed
file_list = []
for root,dir,files in os.walk(BASE_DIR):
    for name in files :
        file_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))


# -- md5sum computation for a single file 
def hashOne(f):
    BLOCKSIZE = 65536
    hasher = hashlib.md5()
    with open(f, 'rb') as afile:
        print f
        buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
        while len(buf) > 0:
            hasher.update(buf)
            buf = afile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
    return hasher.hexdigest()

# parallel calculation of md5sum    
md5 = Parallel(n_jobs=NUM_PROC)(delayed(hashOne)(f) for f in file_list) 

# make an hash of file_names -> md5sum
out_hash = {}
for i in range(len(file_list)):
    out_hash[file_list[i]] = md5[i]

# write out the hash "filename -> md5sum" to disk for future 
dump = json.dumps(out_hash)
with open(OUT_FILE, "wb") as file:
    file.write(dump)
```